# Does the status of being a mussafir have any non-ritual significance?

Tags: fiqh, travelling

Being a mussafir (traveller) has significance for ritual purposes, in particular: I think all schools of law allow shortening prayers and some allow praying prayers during different times than usual, and a mussafir is not required to fast during Ramadan.

I'm wondering whether there are any legal effects of being a mussafir that have nothing to do with ritual obligations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Worship and safar/travelling**

First note that this applies only for two out of three kinds of travel: travel for obedience (like hajj, Jihad, visiting relatives or a sick person etc.) and an allowed travel (like for vacancy) and doesn't apply for travelling for disobedience!

Here shortly a list -without details- of travelling related easements:

- shortening the 4 raka'a fard prayers!
- combining two prayers.
- breaking fast in Ramadan.
- having more time to perform mas-h on the Khufayyn (wiping on leather socks).
- having the permission to miss Jumuah.
- performing nafl prayers while driving/riding.
- leaving out the sunnah prayers except fajr.

**Some virtues of travelling**

It is also recommended for a person which wants to travel to:

- do Istikharah (before travelling).
- to repent (before travelling).
- to pay back his/her duties (before travelling).
- to leave some financial charge/costs for the people he is in charge of (before travelling).
- Not to travel alone.
- to take the leave of his/her family (before travelling).
- to say the [supplication of travel](https://sunnah.com/muslim/15/479).
- to leave on [Thursdays](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/162).
- saying takbeer when going up a place and tasbeeh when going down (see in [sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/202)).
- [performing supplication](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/121) more often!
- when travelling in company [appointing and following a leader](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/15/132).
- dealing and applying the best manners (like patience) during the travel.
- returning back to the family [once finishing the goal of your travel](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/70/57).
- reciting the known du'a (compiled in sahih ibn Khuzaimah, sahih ibn Hebban and al-Mustadrak) before entering a city or village.
- going to the mosque at [first when coming back](https://sunnah.com/urn/180110).
- not to come back to [the family at night](https://sunnah.com/muslim/33/257).

**Conclusion**

Basically there are only worship related effects of being Mussafir. And traveling is considered as a kind of torture -due to the fact that one leaves those whom one loves- therefore it is hardly recommended to turn back as soon as possible.

My basic [souce](http://www.saaid.net/Doat/naif/5.htm) in Arabic.

Comment: "mas-h on the Khufayyn" Could you explain what this means? I don't know those terms and google isn't helpful in this case.